# Exclude id from page redirect (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I've just got some help here on stackoverflow with defining ID attributes such as `/name`. After some work I got my one page site to work with custom IDs. But! Here's my problem:

When the visitor is visiting the index-file for the first time I want the browser to redirect like this:

example.com -> Redirect after 1500 -> example.com/#/all/

But, since it's a one page site, all my other divs (that are hidden when `/all/` is active) are on the same page therefore have the same redirection attribute. So if a user visits a id directly (example.com/#/work/), the browser redirects to `#/all/` after 1500. And therefore making direct linking to certaint projects impossible. Also, I'm having multiple ids that starts with `/work/` .

This is what I'm working with right now

```
window.setTimeout(function() {

window.location.href = '#/all/';    // redirect the visitor when loading the index for the first time
}, 1500);    
$('#/work/...','#/about/').on('ready', function () { // Select ALL that has the id "#/about/", and/or all that starts with the id "#/work/"
    window.location = ""; // No redirect, just load the page with the targeted id active
});
```

Comment: search about session which helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just run the redirection only if no hash is already defined..

```
if (window.location.hash.length === 0){
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.hash = '/all/';    // redirect the visitor when loading the index for the first time
    }, 1500);  
}
```

Comment: .. simple as that. I guess it's all a learning curve. Thank you very much!